# Drop rows before exiting the expression in within()

Tags: r

I want to manipulate a few rows of data without subsetting it first, using `within()`.  In this example, I'd like to order rows 2:4 and be able to remove one of those rows if I want, all without new variable assignment. Consider the data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])
```

I can order the subset of the first column from the 2nd to 4th row with

```
within(dat[2:4,], { x = order(x, decreasing = TRUE) })
```

But the `y` column doesn't get ordered with that call, and I also may want to remove one row from the result before exiting the expression.  So I try the following, which does not seem to work.

```
within(dat[2:4,], {
   x = order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
   y = y[x]                            ## ?? is that the right order?
   `[`(-2, )                           ## how can we subset by row name here?
})
```

I can always subset the result with

```
within(dat[2:4,], {
   x = order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
   y = y[x] 
})[-2, ]
```

But then when I try to re-assign the result, I get an error because I started with three rows.

```
dat[2:4,] <- within(dat[2:4,], {
    x = order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
    y = y[x] 
})[-2, ]
# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2:4, , value = list(x = c(3L, 1L),  : 
#  replacement element 1 has 2 rows, need 3
```

Does anyone have any pointers for this? I'm not too familiar with `within()` and I feel like I'm only missing something very minor.

Comment: R's replacement semantics will create at least one and possibly two temporary dataframe anyway, so it's unlikely you will see any speed or memory efficiencies.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: after subsetting, your data has 2 rows, but you're attempting to replace 3 rows of the original data.

Comment: what exactly do you want as a result? I have the feeling you should be subsetting after your re-assignment.

Comment: Exactly.  In this example, I'd like to order rows 2:4 and be able to remove one of those rows if I want. And I'd really like to learn more about `within()` can do.  It's not well documented, as fas as I can tell.

Comment: I'd put `dat <- dat[-3,]` after you've done the replacement; it's a new operation to be done on the original data.frame, not something you can do from within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a good case for using `data.table` for syntactic and memory efficiency

```
 library(data.table)
 dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = letters[1:5])
 DT <- setDT(copy(dat))


 # replace rows 2:4 with the appropriately ordered subset
  DT[2:4, names(DT) := .SD[order(x,decreasing=TRUE)]]
 DT
#    x y
# 1: 1 a
# 2: 4 d
# 3: 3 c
# 4: 2 b
# 5: 5 e
```

Comment: You know, I still haven't given `data.table` a try.  Looks like it may be able to save me quite a bit of coding. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Accepted since no one has answered using `within()`.  data table seems cleaner anyhow.  Cheers.